# Grabbing cell text from Flexigrid causing problems when using master checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, flexigrid

I have a function that grabs the cell text values from a flexigrid where a checkbox has been checked. But I am having a problem. When I click on the master checkbox(doesnt contain any text values as it is displayed with the column titles) it craps out because of the master checkbox.

This is the error I get: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #`

Here is my function that grabs the Event Date from the Flexigrid:

```
function getSelectedCopyDates() {
            var arr = new Array();
                //for every row that has a checked checkbox
                $("tr").has(".noteCheckBox:checked").each(function (i) {
                        //push the value of column(FName, LName) into the array 
                        arr.push($("#" + this.id + "> td[abbr='EventDate'] > div").text());
                    }
                });
            return arr;

    }
```

And here is a snippet of my flexigrid:

```
 $('#viewNotesGrid').flexigrid({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'get',
            colModel: [
                { display: '<input type="checkbox" class="noteCheckBox" id="checkAllNotes" />', name: 'checkBox', width: 20, sortable: false, align: 'center', process: showDescription },
                { display: 'File ID', name: 'FileID', width: 70, sortable: true, align: 'center', process: showDescription, hide: true },
```

here is what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **$("tr:has(:not('th'))")** selector to select tr without master check box row

```
      $("tr:has(:not('th'))").has(".noteCheckBox:checked").each(function (i) {
          if ($("tr").has(".checkAllNotes:checked")){
                    arr.push($("#" + this.id + "> td[abbr='EventDate'] > div").text());
                }
            });
```

Comment: it is still giving me :Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #  When I click the "checkAllNotes" checkbox. But if I select the checkboxes manually it all works

Comment: check the syntax using **console.log** "#" + this.id + "> td[abbr='EventDate'] > div